# "Нельзя голосовать за/против свое сообщение"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Сейчас сообщение такое "Нельзя голосовать за/против свое сообщение". А подразумевалось видимо такое ""Нельзя голосовать за **или** против свое**го** сообщени**я**", нужно исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил. Строки будут доступны после ближайшего развертывания сборки.