# Нельзя голосовать "за" или "против" своего сообщения. А как можно?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, голосование

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В оригинале там

> You can't vote for your own post

Я понимаю, что если б было "Нельзя голосовать за своё сообщение", то можно было б подумать, что голосовать "против" можно. Но сейчас не менее странно звучит.

Может что-то придумаем на этот счёт?

Comment: Нельзя оценивать свой пост?

Comment: @AntonSorokin никто не может запретить сказать «мой пост говно»

Comment: Предыстория [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2639/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Aer может :D

Comment: Принимать можно)

Comment: И удалять можно (голосовать за удаление)

Comment: @АндрейNOP и голосовать за закрытие тоже.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Голосование недоступно для собственных сообщений.

Comment: Не думаю, что новые варианты ещё появятся. Можно утвердить этот перевод.

Comment: @Suvitruf утвердил

Comment: @Suvitruf и тут как попёрло...

Comment: Лучше поздно, чем никогда :D

Comment: Голосовать за свой ответ нельзя, но его можно отметить как лучший (если сам задавал вопрос и на него же отвечал) Так примерно?

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor вы к чему это спрашиваете?

Comment: Хочу понять логику. Голосовать за свой ответ нельзя, но можно сказать "мой ответ луше всех"

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor и что вас смущает? Свои ответы с галочкой немного по другим критериям обрабатываются нежели чужие.

Answer (score 3):

Просто и незатейливо - "Будьте скромнее..." :)

Comment: Блаженны кроткие, ибо они наследуют StackOverflow на Русском (c) Мф. 5:5

Comment: Такой вариант вполне может допускать голосование "против"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Это уже гордыня :)

Comment: @Harry гордость - предвестник падения.

Comment: @Suvitruf Гордыня и гордость - несколько разные вещи...

Comment: @Harry   ┐( ︶▽︶ )┌

Answer (score 2):

Голосование недоступно для своих сообщений.

Answer (score 1):

Будь моя воля, то тут бы половина перевода была с шуточками :)

В этом случае что то вроде:

"Это как минимум странно - голосовать за себя"

Comment: Ну много где можно) А так да - забавный вариант)) К тому же, та же проблема с "за" и "против", что и в начальном варианте. Хотя лично я считаю, что "голосовать за" может означать не только "за", но и "против".

Comment: А нельзя какой-нибудь плагин/расширение для браузера использовать/написать что бы все переводы были в шутливой форме? Кстати, мне вот не кажется странным голосовать за себя:)). Перевод Harry мне кажется более смешным

Comment: @AntonSorokin боюсь это реверс инжинирингом попахивает, если бы в разметке были ключи оригинальной локализации... или они есть? Сейчас посмотрел - по className можно кое что выдернуть и перевести...

Answer (score 0):

Это ваше сообщение, поэтому проголосовать нельзя.

Comment: А кто-нибудь может минусы пояснить?

Comment: мне в целом не понятны минусы в таких вопросах, от меня плюс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я в таких вопросах минус понимаю либо как "я бы не хотел видеть такой вариант", т. е. 0 - нейтральное отношение, +1 положительное, а -1 совсем отрицательное; либо как "этот ответ принципиально неверен" - например, при ошибках или путанице в терминологии. Вроде как ошибок в терминолигии тут нет (да и их стоило бы отразить в комментариях), так что мне кажется странным, что он всем не нравится...

Comment: он содержит запятую, наверное по этому

Answer (score 0):

> Невозможно проголосовать за свое сообщение.